# jsPDF in React creating space on new line

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I generating a PDF from my React list and everything works well but there is a single space created in the PDF which is making difficult to search for the texts in the PDF i have attached a sample generated PDF for reference if you see the transaction id field you can see there will be a space added on the end of first line. I have tried their repo as well but no documentation for this any help is highly appreciated.

[image: Reference]

This is the code

```
        [
          "Sl.No",
          "Transaction ID",
          "POS Transaction ID",
          "Date",
          "Asset",
          "Received Digital Amount",
          "Received Fiat Amount",
          "Refund Value",
          "Refund Mode"
        ]
      ]
      const finalData: any = []
      currentData.map((item, index) => {
        const arr = []
        arr.push(index + 1)
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "uuid")) {
          arr.push(item.uuid)
        }
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "extPosTransactionId")) {
          arr.push(item.extPosTransactionId)
        }
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "createdAt")) {
          arr.push(dayjs(item.createdAt).format("MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A"))
        }
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "asset")) {
          arr.push(item.asset)
        }
        if (
          Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(
            item,
            "totalDigitalCurrencyReceived"
          )
        ) {
          arr.push(item.totalDigitalCurrencyReceived)
        }
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "totalFiatReceived")) {
          arr.push(`${item.totalFiatReceived} ${item.fiatAsset}`)
        }
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "refundFiatAmount")) {
          arr.push(item.refundStatus == "REFUNDED" ? item.refundFiatAmount : 0)
        }
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, "refundMode")) {
          if (item.refundStatus === "REFUNDED") {
            arr.push(item.refundMode)
          } else {
            arr.push("NA")
          }
        }
        finalData.push(arr)
      })
      const doc = new jsPDF()
      autoTable(doc, {
        head: head,
        body: finalData,
        columnStyles: {
          0: { cellWidth: 10 },
          1: { cellWidth: 38 },
          5: { cellWidth: 15 }
        }
      })

      doc.save("myReports-Transactions.pdf")
```